# Is there a way to see the update deadline time in WSUS?

Tags: wsus

Is there a way to see the update deadline times for updates in WSUS? In the Updates view I can only see if an update has a deadline or not, not the actual time.

This is the deadline time you can set for updates to force them to install by that time.

Comment: It's there if you double-click the actual update.  It sounds like you want the date in the actual update panel, though.

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for a way to do this for all updates. Double-clicking each one would be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of kludgy, but if you have SQL access to SUSDB you could do something like

```
SELECT     TOP (1000) PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdate.DefaultTitle, PUBLIC_VIEWS.vComputerTargetGroup.Name as TargetGroup, PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateApproval.Action, 
                      PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateApproval.Deadline, PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateApproval.CreationDate
FROM         PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateApproval INNER JOIN
                      PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdate ON PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateApproval.UpdateId = PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdate.UpdateId INNER JOIN
                      PUBLIC_VIEWS.vComputerTargetGroup ON 
                      PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdateApproval.ComputerTargetGroupId = PUBLIC_VIEWS.vComputerTargetGroup.ComputerTargetGroupId
WHERE PUBLIC_VIEWS.vUpdate.CreationDate > '7/1/13'
```